# DomPDF - add a footer only on the last page

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to build a PDF with DomPDF, but I need the footer to be *at the very bottom of the page*, but *only on the very last page*.

e.g. Here are a couple of examples of what I want:

[image]

So I know I can get *close* to this with CSS like this:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 240px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: 240px;
}
```

This works in that it sticks the footer at the bottom of the last page, so that's good.

However, it *also* makes it so that the last line of text on the 1st and 2nd page of the 2-page and 3-page PDFs gets pushed down to the next page (because the `margin-bottom: 240px;` ends up getting applied to *every* page, not just the *last* page).

Is there a way to make that `margin-bottom: 240px;` apply to just the *last* page of the PDF, so I don't have a ton of whitespace at the bottom of the not-last-page's of the PDF?

Comment: why not set a margin-top on the footer?

Comment: Does that help me in some way...? I guess I'm not really following what you're trying to tell me...

Comment: Reading your question it seems to me that `.content` is being used on every single page, whereas the footer is now only used on the last. So instead of setting the margin on your `.content`, set it on your `footer` so this margin is not applied to all pages. Well, that is how I think it could help you.

Comment: Are you able to get that to actually work in DomPDF? I have tried your suggestion here, and it just seems to make DomPDF do weird stuff and not actually fix the problem. Could you post an example?

Comment: I see your point now. With the fixed position, text may run underneath your footer, right?

Comment: I think you will have to check with PHP for the last page and then add the footer it.

Comment: Yeah I can't see a way to actually check to see if it's the last page though? And even then, I'd need to know how far down the last page the content ran, to know whether the footer should go on the last page, or to add a page and put it there.